# Dynamic eventAction and eventLabel with Google Analytics (analytics.js)

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

I want to track which button is pressed based on the data-order attribute on the button. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I've been trying this:

```
$('display-section__content-hero').click(function(){
  var $id = $(this).data('order');

  ga('send', 'event', 'Clicks', 'Content Hero' + $id, 'Opened' + $id);
})
```

Haven't gotten any data so far because I just don't have any traffic, wondering if I'm going down the right route or if this isn't even possible?

Comment: That should not be a problem. If you use Chrome you can install the Google Analytics Debugger extension (it will show up under Developer Tools and send it's output to the console) - a call to Analytics should be displayed in the console when you click the button. Also if everything works events should immediately show up in the realtime console.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Eike!!